# Is it possible to use the google speech api offline?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-speech

For IVR application, I have integrated the google speech API. Its working fine.

But When I deploy the same in client location, there is no internet facility available.

So is it possible to use the google speech API offline in linux machines

Comment: It is not possible to use Google cloud speech api offline. Google cloud means that your app is interacting with online algorithms to process image, speech etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use Google cloud speech api offline. Google cloud means that your app is interacting with online algorithms to process image, speech etc.

Comment: I do not have any source.